# system dependencies of R package without root access

Tags: r

I'm developing an R package that has system dependencies (much of the package is in C++) and looking into best practices for distributing. I believe there is no way to distribute system packages with an R package. Seems this issue has gotten some attention lately in [this thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/dependencies-on-system-packages-td3259395.html).

Suppose the user does not have root access, and is using a local installation of R. What's the best way for them to obtain these packages locally? Is it as simple as downloading the shared libraries, and adding them to $R_HOME/Libraries? Or is it best for them to download dependencies into a local folder and set LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

I'm fairly new to R, so I'm wondering if there is a "preferred" solution for the best end user experience.

Answer (score 2):

If they are in fact system libraries, simply depend upon them and possibly test via autoconf. Many CRAN packages do the same.

Reinventing how shared libraries are deployed is best left to the operating system, linux distribution, system administrator, .... rather than to your user-space application.

Comment: Dirk, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that's just a really unattractive option for us. This is an academic application that is most often used on large computing clusters, where users often keep their own local installation of R with the packages they need. Administrators can be hesitant to add system packages for each user request. I do think this would be a useful addition to the R environment.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the `bigmemory` package for one approach - it includes a non-trivial subset (16 meg worth) of boost.

Comment: Not really as those are template headers which get munged at compile time; OP wants a hack for libraries.  Ben's answer is closer.

Comment: Ooops, could have sworn those were `.cpp` files.  It's amazing that boost has 16 meg of header files!

Comment: There are a few packages which all ship Boost headers (in a pure template use) so we had discussions about creating a common one they all would depend upon.

Answer (score 0):

You can include anything you want in the `inst/` directory, including a `lib` subdirectory. If all you want is to be able to access those libraries at runtime, you can probably use something like `Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH=system.file("lib",package="mypkg"))` to set the library paths accordingly.

If you need the libraries for linking at install/build time it could be a bit more of a nuisance. I can imagine that you could set up your configure scripts and Makefiles (pp. 13-15 of the R extensions manual) to look in the right place ... but I don't know how to do this and it would probably take some futzing around to do it (please document it if you do it!)

Note that packages incorporating binary files are not allowed on CRAN (for obvious security reasons), although R-Forge does allow them ...

(None of this advice is tested -- I have distributed binary *executables* within packages, but never libraries -- so I hope it's helpful, or at least not misleading.)